# How can I debug a my Solidity smart contract with a GUI?

Tags: solidity, remix, contract-debugging, testnets, ganache

Is there any way to debug a Solidity smart contract with a GUI, like remix?

How can I do it for both testnets and mainnet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I wrote an article](https://medium.com/authereum/debugging-solidity-with-a-gui-remix-and-ganache-c6c16488fcfd) about how to do just this!

---

You can use [`remixd`](https://github.com/ejwessel/GanacheTimeTraveler#reverttosnapshotid_to_revert_to) and [`remix`](https://remix.ethereum.org) to test and debug your contracts with a GUI (remix). The steps to do this are:

1. Install `remixd` with `npm install -g remixd`
2. Run `remixd` with `remixd -s <absolute-path> --remix-ide https://remix.ethereum.org`
3. Attach your project to remix.ethereum.org
4. Run ganache-cli in the terminal with `ganache-cli`
5. Choose “Web3 Provider” as your “Environment” in remix
6. Test your code with a GUI (remix)

The article dives deeper into each step, but you should be able to achieve your goals with just those 6 steps!

> How can I do it for both testnets and mainnet?

You can perform the same steps above on mainnet or a testnet by connected Remix to a node on one of those networks. When prompted with the "Environment" in remix, you would simply use a node on the desired network!

Comment: Hey, I would like to debug [a transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xdcccbae489c2e6f81c532bf549a6c376402c12ec4aa7f4e3b2d5eb77dc430dac) that has been confirmed on the blockchain. How can I do this? I have figured out how to load in a deployed smart contract, but can't figure out how to load in a mined transaction.

Comment: Edit: I have figured out that you can enable a debug pane on the left by enabling the debugging plugin, however when I debug a transaction all sections say "no data available", and I can't debug anything.