# How to debug a reverted transaction?

Tags: solidity

I am writing a smart contract. The smart contract always revert. How can I debug step by step my smart contract?
I am coming from javascript, so I was expecting a "console.log" or something like this.

I don't understand how to do it with remixIde...etc.

I don't understand how to debug my smartcontract. Any help?

Regards,

Stéphane

Comment: Hi there. Have a look at Remix's debugger -> https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugger.html

Comment: This question might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/76082/how-can-i-debug-a-my-solidity-smart-contract-with-a-gui?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use hardhat to setup your smart contracts. From there you can use `console.log`